# Create an automation to fetch data from FTP and create a DE that updates every day

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, ftp

I want to create an automation that pulls the data from the FTP to salesforce and creates a data extension that gets updated every day.

The problem is that the folder where the data is located is already in use for another automation and it doesn't let me use it showing as being locked(error message attached)

Is there a work around this?

Is there an option to change the settings to allow a folder to be used in more then one automation, if presumably this is the issue?

Can I create the automation in another way?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you using the standard Import directory?

Comment: yes, I'm using the standard import directory

Comment: @CodeRage, any idea that I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a message you get when you're trying to use files from a folder without specifiying a Filename Pattern.

What you need to do is check "Use Filename Pattern" with a specific word that can be found in the filename, and then afterwords select your folder.

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks a lot